# Need help with convolution problem.

Tags: integration, convolution

I'm just learning about the convolution integral and am stuck on this example problem:

> Given 
>   $x_1(t) = \left \{\begin{array}{lr} 1 :  0 < x < 1 \\ 0: \text{elsewhere}     \end{array} \right.,\text{ and}$ 
>  
> $\\ x_2(t) = \left \{\begin{array}{lr} 1 :  0 < x < 1 \\ 2: 1 < x < 2 \\ 0: \text{elsewhere} \end{array} \right.$
>   
>   
>   Convolve $x_1$ and $x_2$ graphically.

I have approached the problem as follows:

Graph of $x_1$ and $x_2$:

[image: Graph of $x_1$]

[image: Graph of $x_2$]

I will do $x_2 * x_1 = \int_0^t\ {x_2(\lambda)x_1(t-\lambda)\ d\lambda}$, and thus:

$\forall t < 0: x_2 * x_1 = 0 \text{, since }x_1(t - \lambda) \text{ and } x_2(\lambda) \text{ do not overlap here. Similarly,} \\ \forall t > 3: x_2 * x_1 = 0. \\ 0 < t < 1: x_2 * x_1 = t \text{, since  the product of }x_1(t - \lambda) \text{ and } x_2(\lambda) \text{ is 1 here}$ $\\ \text{and is integrated from 0 to } t. \\ 1 < t < 2: x_2 * x_1 = 2t -2 \text{, since the prodcut of } x_1(t - \lambda) \text{ and } x_2(\lambda) \\ \text{ is 2 here and is integrated from 1 to t. This interval is where I'm having trouble;} \\ \text{ the book tells me I should be getting } t. \\ 2 < t < 3: x_2*x_1 = 6 - 2t \text{, since the product is 2 here and is integrated from } t - 1 \text{ to 2}.$

I haven't illustrated the convlution process graphically here.

I'm grateful for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $1<t<2$, the product of $x_1(t-\lambda)$ and $x_2(\lambda)$ is indeed $2$ when $1<\lambda<t$, but the product also equals $1$ when $t-1<\lambda<1$.

Comment: Uhhh, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for pointing it out! So I split the integral from 1 to 2 to two integrals from t - 1 to 1 and 1 to t (1 < t < 2) and get 2 - t and 2t - 2 respectively. Is that correct? But then I end up with two functions for this interval of t rather than just one as the book claims; although just adding those two gives me the desired function, I can't see why I should from a theoretical standpoint. But I'll take a guess and you can tell me if I'm right; since the convolution is given as the area under the product, and the area under this product is given by ...

Comment: two functions, the total area is simply the sum. Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're right; but that's not the way I would phrase it. The product of $x_1(t-\lambda)$ and $x_2(\lambda)$ (for some fixed $t$ between $1$ and $2$) isn't two functions of $\lambda$; rather, it's a single function of $\lambda$, whose definition happens to require more than one line to write down.

Comment: Oh I see, right. Thanks for the input Greg!